# How to pass a variable from handler in React to other area of code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not a pro with JS and React (just started about 2-3 months ago) and now trying to modify one of the project where I am working. Most of my issues with scopes in React. Below is the code where I am trying to pass an array of objects from Button onClick handler to component which generates excel file.

Handler part is a child of main component and render part - part of the same component.

Handler:

const Reports = (props) => { ....

```
let xlsxFileHandler =() => {
if (dataSource) {
    table = document.querySelectorAll("table");
    table1=table[0];
    table2=table[1];
    output = document.querySelector("pre");
    data2 = parseTable(table1,table2);  
}
}   

...
```

render part:

```
return (
        <>
            <Layout> ....


<ExcelFile element={<button>Download Excel 2</button>}>
                    <ExcelSheet data={data2} name="Employees">
                        <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="card_number"/>
                        <ExcelColumn label="Wallet Money" value="controller_address"/>
                        <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="department_abbreviation"/>
                        <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="department_name"/>
                        <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="event_code_code"/>
                        <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="event_code_name"/>
                        <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="first_name"/>
                        <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="id"/>
                    </ExcelSheet>
                </ExcelFile>
```

......

I could not pass data2 variable to render part, it says undefined:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

```
   at t.value (ExcelFile.js:66)
    at ExcelFile.js:96
    at D (react.production.min.js:18)
    at e (react.production.min.js:17)
    at R (react.production.min.js:18)
    at Object.forEach (react.production.min.js:20)
    at t.value (ExcelFile.js:94)
    at Object.s (react-dom.production.min.js:14)
    at d (react-dom.production.min.js:14)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:14
```

If I pass the data2 as callback from render to hanlder it says almost the same and page is blank. How I can access react table in runtime? As I understand I can't just directly access to React DOM.

Same time I can console.log the data2 in handler of click:

0: {Фамилия: " ", Имя: " ", Отчество: " ", Департамент: " ", Проходная: " ", …}
"", …}
..... more items with data
length: 65
**proto**: Array(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the value of `data2` in a state.
If you are using Class Component. Example from https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html :

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If you are using Function component. Example from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html:

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react';

  function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
      <div>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
         Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

from [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-state-react/#:~:text=What%20is%20State%3F,the%20lifetime%20of%20the%20component](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-state-react/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20State%3F,the%20lifetime%20of%20the%20component).

> The state is an instance of React Component Class can be defined as an object of a set of observable properties that control the behavior of the component. In other words, the State of a component is an object that holds some information that may change over the lifetime of the component.

I would say that a state is the equivalent of a `let` in a React component. So if you need a var that his value will change during the component lifetime, you need a State

Comment: Thanks for example, but I expected a more explanation about a state, For me still not clear what is the const [data2, setData2]. Is it array or what else?

Comment: Edited the anwser with some details

Comment: It's too complicate for just for passing one object to other scope of code. Is there any easier, a shorter solution? Might be useContext? Please consider existing code environment and circumstances. I do mean, it's tough to modify the existing app.

Comment: Okay, I've made my state as: const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]); Then now, how to link that data2 to my State?

Comment: Instead of data2 = parseTable(table1,table2);  You can use setMyData( parseTable(table1,table2)); and use myData in your render return

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. With setMyData( parseTable(table1,table2)); - finally I could passed that variable to render part. This is saved me.